# How to hang a 170 pound board onto a brick building

Tags: construction

I need to hang a 20 feet wide by 12 feet high wood billboard flat onto a 50 year old brick and mortar building. The board weighs 170 pounds. I want to bolt it to the mortar not the bricks. How do I do this? Is 170 pounds to heavy? The bricks are standard size bricks, nothing unusual.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are you sure this board is 20 feet long by 12 feet high? (Edit your question to clarify.) And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of this board? Will it carry a load itself? What's the construction of the wall and age of the building? Please provide details and context so that we can respond with confidence and so the question is more useful to the community. Be _Thorough Eddie_ on SE.

Comment: so this board is going flat against the wall over its full size something like like a billboard?  why do you want to attach to the mortar?

Comment: Yes, The board is 20 feet wide by 12 feet high.

Comment: The board is a billboard. It will not carry a load. The building is brick and mortar about 50 years old.

Comment: When attaching a board like this flat to the brick building, it is customary to go through the mortar, not the brick. The brick can crumble.

Comment: There's still not enough information here to provide an answer. What anchor mechanism does the billboard have? Why aren't typical masonry anchors suitable?

Comment: @FastEddie, I think you have some misconception about mortar.  People drill and hang from the mortar because its easier to drill and easier to patch later, not because it's more secure.

Comment: The anchor mechanism, etc, is what I am looking for, hence my question, “How ...”

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I chose mortar because of the age of the bricks which are 50 years old.